# Graphics card clicking during POST

Tags: graphics-card, post, clicking-sound

During the POST the graphics card makes a rhythmic clicking sound and the post lasts much longer than usual. However after 5-10 seconds the computer boots as normal.

When I remove the graphics card the sounds stop and when using a different graphics card there are no sounds made.

I haven't encountered a problem like this before dose anyone have any idea why these sounds are being made?

Comment: Does the clicking sound continue after the computer boots up?

Comment: Sounds like its obviously something wrong with that graphics cards hardware. The clicking is not from the fan correct? more from the Ram or GPU?

Comment: No, once the computer starts up the sound stops. However I have not stress tested the graphics yet.

Comment: If, while it's clicking, you stick your finger (or something safer) into the GPU fan to stop it, does the clicking stop? If not, then it's probably an electrical discharge you're hearing, meaning failed hardware.  Have you confirmed it was not coming from the PSU (most more often the source of electricity discharge noises)?

Comment: If you can, try a different GPU power cable off the same PSU. Also try that GPU in a different PC if you can. It's most likely the PSU as techie007 is elluding to but could still be the GPU fan if you're lucky. If you happen to have an extra PSU you could also plug it in and use the power lines from that to power your GPU externally.

Comment: @Enigma Now that I thought about it the new card is using a 6 pin cable from the PSU, which the other one didn't, is it possible that it is this cable that is causing the problem?